# How to fix uneven rows in Bootstrap if you're using a WordPress loop?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following `div` in my loop:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
   *all my mark-up*
</div>
```

So it's outputting my posts, but they have different heights creating uneven rows. Normally I'd add the following `div` after every x "`col-*`" to clear them with:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
```

But since the divs are outputted by the loop, I can't do that, well I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `min-height` to your columns.

Comment: Setting a min-height does work, but but it doesn't make it fluid, like I'm looking for some sort of `clear` solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child(3n+1)` to target the first block of each line (except the first line). You can then give a `clear:both` property to that block, so that the previous line is properly cleared.

Working pen : http://codepen.io/Brachamul/pen/zBKKda

Here I used `div:nth-child(3n+1) { clear: both }`

Comment: You're on the right track but instead of posting an answer with another question, you should post a working example that solves the issue.

Comment: Since it's every 4 this is the css 1.col-md-3:nth-child(4n+4)::after` and I got it working by showing something like `"!"`after every 4th item, but it wouldn't clear even with `clear:both;`.

Comment: @DarrenBachan It's every three, because you are dividing a 12-column grid in 4 parts, so there should be 3 blocks per line. It's (3n+1) because you're applying the clearfix to the block that's after each line, rather than to the last block of each line.